# Bhagvatam and planet moon

Tags: bhagavata-purana, prabhupada

While reading quotes of Prabhupada (bhaktivedanta swami) I found that Moon is farther than the Sun and the planet/satellite is not Moon.

> 1975 [Conversations](https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Moon_planet_is_further_(than_the_sun)%3F) and Morning Walks
>
> Yes. It is far, far away. Their calculation is wrong. They are going
>   to a wrong planet.
>
> Morning Walk -- May 12, 1975, Perth:
>
> Prabhupāda: (in car) They have not gone to the moon planet.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: Really?
>
> Prabhupāda: Yes. It is far, far away. Their calculation is wrong. They
>   are going to a wrong planet.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: It must be the Rahu planet.
>
> Prabhupāda: Yes, or something else. Not moon planet.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: How many...
>
> Prabhupāda: It is above the sun planet.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: Moon planet is further?
>
> Prabhupāda: Yes.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: Oh. Because they say that the moon planet is the closest
>   planet to the earth. That is their calculation. And they say that it
>   orbits around the earth, and then that the earth orbits the sun.
>
> Prabhupāda: All wrong. What is the... According to them, what is the
>   distance of sun planet?
>
> Paramahaṁsa: Sun planet is 93,000,000 miles.
>
> Gaṇeśa: They say the moon planet is only 250,000 miles.
>
> Prabhupāda: It is wrong thing.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: Is their calculation for the distance of the sun wrong
>   also?
>
> Prabhupāda: Yes.
>
> Paramahaṁsa: 93,000,000? It says in the Bhāgavatam exactly what the
>   distance?
>
> Prabhupāda: The whole universe, diameter, is pañcaśat-koṭi-yojana. One
>   yojana equal to eight miles, and one koti is ten miles, er, ten
>   million. So pañcaśata, fifty into 10,000,000 into eight.

So what is the exact position of Moon as per the Bhagvatam and what is its distance from the Sun ?

[NASA moon landing hoax](https://krishna.org/nasa-moon-landing-hoax-explained-by-srila-prabhupada/)

Comment: Who are these people - Ganesha, Paramhamsa? I hope it's not Lord Ganesha.

Comment: @Rickross his pupil in conversation

Comment: @YDS not vedas. Bhagvatam

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That Q's wordings r wrong...it should be Puranas or may be in the Q's context Vedas mean all Hindu scriptures...bdw answer of that Q is from Bhagvata & Vishnu Puranas...

Comment: Because of sv this happened..